# Regarding C API for SQLITE database

Tags: c, sqlite

Is there any chance to insert/retrieve image file into/from  sqlite database using C API?
If so any suggest me the code for me using  the following methods

```
int sqlite_encode_binary(const unsigned char *in, int n, unsigned char *out);
int sqlite_decode_binary(const unsigned char *in, unsigned char *out);
```

?

Comment: Why do you think you need to encode/decode something? Binary data stored in BLOBs is *not* changed in any way.

Answer (score 1):

No, SQLite won't read the file for you. You will have to read the data
into memory yourself, then insert it into the table (you could possibly
use memory-mapped files - see `CreateFileMapping` on Windows, `mmap` on
Linux). The easiest way is perhaps to use a parameterized query - see
[`sqlite3_bind_blob`](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/bind_blob.html).